# Android - Firebase query startAt not working as expected

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am developing an Android app using Firebase as backend. 
I am new to Firebase and stuck at a problem, well the problem is when I try to search for a record using `startAt` query, it returns results which does not starts with the keyword I enters.

Here's the data set

```
itemname
    -KK8vI8A5BZZp3Xo3FpA
       name: "abc"
    -KK8w3uoJdJ0hBSrq0CS
       name: "test"
    -KKAC1o9Vazyg9JLtDoQ
       name: "dude"
```

And here's the code snippit

```
Query query = firebase.child(Constants.KEY_ITEM_NAME).orderByChild("name").startAt("abc");
        query.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                Iterator<DataSnapshot> i = dataSnapshot.getChildren().iterator();
                while (i.hasNext()) {
                    DataSnapshot d = i.next();
                    LOG(d.getKey(), d.getValue().toString());
                }
            }
```

So when I search for `abc` the response also includes `test`.
Maybe I am doing something wrong or I am going the wrong way. 
Could anyone please point me in right direction.

P.S I am trying to use an `AutocompleteTextView` to search items.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

When you call `orderByChild("name").startAt("abc")` the database orders all items by their name property, skips the ones before `abc` and then returns them all.

If you're only looking to return children that match `abc`, you'd use `equalTo()`:

```
query = firebase.child(Constants.KEY_ITEM_NAME).orderByChild("name").equalTo("abc");
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, yes I've used equalTo() but I am trying to use this query in `AutoCompleteTextView` and if I've more items lets say names are `abc` , `abd` , `abe` and I want to search for all records that starts with `ab`. How can I achieve this?

Comment: I even tried using this way `firebase.child("itemname").orderByKey().startAt("a").endAt("a\uf8ff");`
But null response.

Comment: Worked when used `.orderByChild("name").startAt("ab").endAt("ab\uf8ff");`

Comment: Great to hear how you solved it. I've made a note that we need to add that example back into the firebase.google.com version of the docs.

Comment: Yes this works, but it does not find "ab" itself then. So how can you get every value that starts with "ab" and which also matches/equals "ab"?

Comment: While I also would love to know solution to that in one query, you can probably just run two queries and combine their results. One like above, and one that uses equalTo().

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can't do what you want. I presume the method you're searching for is `startsWith()` and not `startAt()` (to match all words begining with a substring). This method hasn't been implemented yet in Firebase, too bad.

You have to use an external service like ElasticSearch but that would mean you must have a server which is probably one of reason you actually use firebase... Anyway this is a link for implementing ElasticSearch:

https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/01/queries-part-2-advanced-searches-with.html

Otherwise you'll have to figure out how to get rid of your search bar...

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Worked for me:

```
        Query query = MyApplication.sReferenceOrders.orderByChild(Constants.STATUS).startAt("1").endAt("1\\uf8ff");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to implement search feature to your app ..
this is my query

```
 private void searchForMatch(String keyword) {
    Log.d(TAG, "SearchForMatch: searching for match");
    mUserList.clear();
    if (keyword == null) {
        mUserList.clear();
    } else {
        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        Query query = reference.child("where you want to search in database ")
                .orderByChild("what do you want search from your database").startAt(keyword).endAt(keyword + "\uf8ff");
        query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot singlesnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onDataChange: found user" + singlesnapshot.getValue(User.class).toString());
                    mUserList.add(singlesnapshot.getValue(User.class));
                   this is my list adapter for displaying search results // updateUsersList();


                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }


}
```

If you don't know how it works then check out [this tutorial on youtube.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b_tz8kbFUsU)

Answer (score -1):

I too was looking for this solution, thanks.
I tried it, and even works with this:

```
startAt('ab').endAt('ab\w|\W');
```