# FirebaseListAdapter ignores orderByChild() and equalTo()

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, kotlin

So, I want to make a `FirebaseListAdapter` to display autocomplete suggestion as after the user types in at least X (in my case, 1) character(s).

```
val mSearchSuggestionsListView = findViewById(R.id.main_list_view) as ListView
var suggestionAdapter: FirebaseSuggestionAdapter? = null

mSearchEditText.editText.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
    override fun afterTextChanged(editable: Editable) {
        if (editable.length > 1) {
            ...
            createNewSuggestionAutoComplete(editable.toString().toLowerCase())
            ...
        } else {
            mSearchSuggestionsListView.adapter = null
        }
    }
    ...
    //Other overrides trimmed 
})


fun createNewSuggestionAutoComplete(query: String) {
    val ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("myModels")
            .orderByChild("name").equalTo(query).ref
    suggestionAdapter = FirebaseSuggestionAdapter(ref)
    ...
    mSearchSuggestionsListView.adapter = suggestionAdapter
    ...
}

inner class FirebaseSuggestionAdapter(ref: DatabaseReference) :
        FirebaseListAdapter<MyModel>(this@MainActivity, MyModel::class.java, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, ref) {
    override fun populateView(v: View, model: MyModel, position: Int) {
        v.findViewById<TextView>(android.R.id.text1).text = model.name
    }
}
```

And here's the `MyModel` class:

```
class MyModel(var name: String)
```

Here's the data in the realtime database:

```
-myModels
--0
---name: "beef"
--1
---name: "vegetable"
--2
---name: "bean"
```

And here's the firebase index rule for above database:

```
{
    "rules": {
        "myModels": {
            ".indexOn": ["name"]
        },
    }
}
```

And somehow, the result, after I typed in > 1 characters, no matter what the characters are, is always, like this (in this exact order).

```
beef
vegetable
bean
```

(What I mean by "no matter", of course includes each of the following strings: "beef", "vegetable", or "bean" (1 word at a time) and even a nonsense slam-the-keyboard combination such as "igiviibbi")

P.S There're some code I trimmed to shorten the snippet, such as:

1. Delay to display suggestion after each typing to prevent excessive call.
2. `suggestionAdapter.cleanup()` call before beginning creating a new instance of it in `createNewSuggestionAutoComplete()`

P.S.S Other details.

1. The reason I use `MyModel` instead of a mere `String` is because I want to add some other fields as well.
2. I tried `startAt()` as well before doing it with `equalTo()` in above code, but they both do / display the exact same problem / results.
3. Btw above code is written in Kotlin. But I think it's not the cause of this problem.

Any suggestion on how to properly display the data as the `FirebaseQuery` specify in the `ref`?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was implementing the `FirebaseListAdapter` wrongly.

I should pass `Query`, instead of `DatabaseReference`, to `FirebaseListAdapter` last parameter. (The editor didn't spot an error because `DatabaseReference` also inherit from `Query`)

So, it should be:

```
fun createNewSuggestionAutoComplete(query: String) {
    val q = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("myModels")
            .orderByChild("name").equalTo(query)
    suggestionAdapter = FirebaseSuggestionAdapter(q)
    ...
    mSearchSuggestionsListView.adapter = suggestionAdapter
    ...
}

inner class FirebaseSuggestionAdapter(q: Query) :
        FirebaseListAdapter<MyModel>(this@MainActivity, MyModel::class.java, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, q) {
    override fun populateView(v: View, model: MyModel, position: Int) {
        v.findViewById<TextView>(android.R.id.text1).text = model.name
}
```

Unfortunately, the `startAt()` in Firebase is not `startWith()`, so rather than returns `beef` & `bean` when you typed in `bee`, it returns **each node** , starting with name = `bee` (exactly "bee"), until the last node (if you don't specify `endAt()`.

If it doesn't find any `bee` it will return all nodes instead.

If you want to use something like `startWith()`, unfortunately Firebase still doesn't support that kind of query.

There's however, a library called [QueryBase](https://github.com/davideast/Querybase) which maybe help with your case. it's written by a firebaser as well. (JS only)

This may help you as well [Android - Firebase query startAt not working as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37798366/android-firebase-query-startat-not-working-as-expected)