# Query firebase database and retrieve limited data

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have an android application that uses `Firebase` database. `Firebase` database structure looks like:

[image]

Each child of `Users` is a `username` of different user.

#### What i want

i have a search field in my application on which i have attached a `TextChangedListener`. This search field can be used to search for `usernames` of other users.

Now when a user enters any text in the search field for example `jo`, i want to fetch **first 20 usernames** from the database that start with `jo`, in my case, it would return `john_jj` and all other usernames that start with `jo`.

Something equivalent to:

```
SELECT username 
FROM table 
WHERE username LIKE 'jo%' 
LIMIT 20;
```

#### Question

How can I write a query to get first 20 usernames from Firebase database that start with specific alphabets, like `jo`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This:

```
SELECT username 
FROM table 
WHERE username LIKE 'jo%' 
LIMIT 20;
```

can be like this in firebase:

```
DatabaseReference ref=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
ref.orderByChild(username).startAt("jo").endAt("jo\uf8ff").limitToFirst(20).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener(){

@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    for(DataSnapshot data: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
       String usernames=data.getKey();
    }
}

@Override
public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

  }
});
```

`child("Users")` is the table

`orderByChild(username)` is the column

`startAt("jo").endAt("jo\uf8ff")` is this LIKE 'jo%'

`limitToFirst(20)` is this LIMIT 20;

for more info about queries in firebase check this: [Queries in Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Query)

Comment: Great answer Peter! I'd recommend using a `ChildEventListener` though (or showing how to loop over `DataSnapshot.getChildren()`) to ensure the users show up in the correct order.

Comment: Thank you @FrankvanPuffelen! I added `DataSnapshot.getChildren()`, the `keys` should be the username since he is looping inside of them.(if im not wrong)

Comment: @PeterHaddad thankyou for your answer. I have tried what you suggested  and tried to `Log` usernames that are returned. It returns `john_jj` but it also returns all the usernames that come after the `john_jj`. I think its because we are only specifying `startAt` but not `endAt`

Comment: @PeterHaddad my guess is that `startAt("jo")` is not equivalent to `LIKE 'jo%'`

Comment: try and use it with `endAt()` after `startAt()`. As when you commented I saw this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37798366/android-firebase-query-startat-not-working-as-expected/39065609

Comment: To only get `jo%` use `startAt("jo").endAt("jo\uf8ff")...`. The `\uf8ff` is simply the last character in unicode, so acts as an end guard.

Comment: Problem solved. Really thankful to both of you guys.

Comment: Very good answer @PeterHaddad ! For a better understanding, I also recomand you Nick see this tutorial, [The Firebase Database For SQL Developers](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLlP-k-RKFa7RyNPa9_wCH2s).

Comment: Just did it. Cheers body!