# How to sort and filter data in Firebase?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to make a query in order to get all children under `bookings` node that  contain the the child key `TimeStampDateAndTime` and the value of the child is between 1519912278 and 1520689878. For some reason it returns null even though the value of the key TimeStampDateAndTime in the JSON object shown below is in this range 1519912278 - 1520689878.

```
let ref = dbRef.child("Cleaners").child(self.uidOfTextField!).child("bookings").queryOrdered(byChild: "TimeStampDateAndTime").queryStarting(atValue: 1519912278).queryEnding(atValue: 1520689878)

finalRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot) in         
    print("snapshot.value is  line 81 is \(snapshot.value)") //prints (<null>)
}

"Cleaners" : {
    "05MSPgkP1ddhFqXDRjIB4npGEPV2" : {
        "bookings" : {
             "392239680" : {
                  "BookingAmount" : “10”,
                  "BookingCompleted" : "false",
                  "TimeStampDateAndTime" : "1520526600",
           },
       }
   },
 }
```

Comment: try `queryStarting(atValue: 1520526600)` just to see what will you get

Comment: @PeterHaddad it works if I try just with `queryStarting(atValue: 1520526600)`

Comment: @bibscy What about using string values of the timestamps in `queryStarting/queryEnding`?

Comment: @EDUsta it return `null` if I try `.queryStarting(atValue: "1519912278").queryEnding(atValue: 1520689878)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It gives you null because it does not exists, you need to do something like this:

```
queryOrdered(byChild: "TimeStampDateAndTime").queryStarting(atValue: 152).queryEnding(atValue: 152\uf8ff)
```

this will give you all `TimeStampDateAndTime` that have 152 at the beginning

Comment: The problem is that value of key TimeStampDateAndTime is saved as string rather than Int. So it's "1520526600", rather than 1520526600, therefore Firebase when we call `queryOrderedByChild ` Firebase doesn't infer that we want to order Int values and not String, so I assume the result will be different.

Comment: It is working, I was just trying to understand how it may affect the result given that I should have saved the values as Int rather than String. I don't want to store as Int, because I have so many places where I have to change the type of that variable. That's why I was inquiring further to see if result would be affected or no. Firebase say "Strings come after numbers and are sorted lexicographically in ascending order." Now I don't know how they order `String(Int)`

Comment: yes check this to do a where clause in firebase: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26700924/query-based-on-multiple-where-clauses-in-firebase. I think if you do "152" it will behave the same also as it will knw that it should start with "152". https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37798366/android-firebase-query-startat-not-working-as-expected

Comment: Given my database structure, I want to make a query and observe `Cleaners` node and get all objects located at path `Cleaner/uid/bookings/bookingNumber` that contain key `TimeStampDateAndTime` and then apply a filter method like `.queryStartingAt.` 
         The problem is that each booking object is nested under each uid and I want to get all bookings under all uid's that meet condition.

Comment: please ask it as a different question with more explanation, maybe someone suggests you a different database structure that can suit you

Answer (score 1):

"TimeStampDateAndTime" is a string in your case, so ordering by it won't give the expected results. You can change its type to Int.

Comment: is there any way to get the expected result without changing in the database the type of "TimeStampDateAndTime" from String to Int?

Comment: Without updating the current values in your database, I don't think so.